# How many 14ers did I climb?

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art, parsing

In mountaineering terminology, a "14er" is any mountain with an elevation of 14 000 feet or more. However, there is another distinction. For a peak to count as a 14er, it must also have a "geographic prominence" of 300 or more feet. This means that to move from one 14er to another, you must first descend *at least* 300 feet before rising again. Take this example. Line 1 counts as 14 000 feet, and each line counts as 100 feet.

```
  /\__/\  
 /      \ 
/        \
```

Now, both of these peaks have enough elevation to count, but there isn't enough drop in elevation between them to count as two separate peaks. Therefore, one of these counts as a 14er, and the other one is just a "partial peak". Here is an example where the two peaks count as two separate 14er:

```
   /\    /\   
  /  \  /  \  
 /    \/    \ 
/            \
```

There can also be a partial peak on the decline between two 14ers. Here's a slightly modified version of the last mountain range:

```
   /\      /\   
  /  \/\  /  \  
 /      \/    \ 
/              \
```

This mountain range also counts as two 14ers.

You must write a program or function that takes an ascii-art representation of a mountain range, and return how many 14ers are in the range. You can take input in whatever format is most convenient for you, be it 2D array of characters, a string with newline, or a string with some other delimiter. You can assume that all inputs will only contain the characters `/\_`, and that the length of each line will be the same (including trailing spaces). You can also assume that the mountain range starts on the bottom left corner with either a `/` or a `_`.

If the last section of a mountain is not on the bottom line, you can assume that the mountain only decreases after that, e.g.

```
  /
 /
/
```

Counts as a single 14er.

You do not have to handle invalid mountain ranges.

Here is some sample I/O:

```
         /\___/\_             
        /        \    /\      
       /          \  /  \     
   _/\/            \/    \    
  /                       \   
 /                         \  
/                           \_

2

                  /\    /\
         /\      /  \  /  
  /\    /  \    /    \/   
 /  \  /    \  /          
/    \/      \/           

4

       /\                 
 _/\__/  \                
/         \               

1

      /\                  
     /  \   /\            
    /    \_/  \           
   /           \          
  /             \         
 /               \        
/                 \       

1

              /\          
    /\_/\    /  \_        
   /     \  /     \     /\
  /       \/       \   /  
 /                  \_/   
/                         

3
```

Comment: So the starting line counts as 14,000 feet?

Comment: @R.Kap Yes, I believe that's correct, assuming you mean the bottom line when you say starting line.

Comment: And you always begin with a 14er?

Comment: Is a trailing newline admissible?

Comment: Related: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/68967/how-many-peaks-in-my-mountain-range

Comment: I think you should mention somewhere that a `_` counts as 100 feet lower than a slash on the same line. At least that's what your last test case suggests.

Comment: I can feel a Retina answer coming...

Comment: The spec seems thin... can we have a flat peat like `/ / / _ \ \ \ ` ? Also, I suppose that the highest point in the input should always be counted as a peak but this is not explicitly specified; one could start at a lower peak and end up with a different count.

Comment: Will it always be continous? Will it have at most one nonspace character for each column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## JavaScript (ES6), 133 bytes

```js
s=>[...s].map((_,i)=>(c=s[i%h*w+i/h|0])=="/"?++a>2&&(p+=!d,d=a=3):c=="\\"&&--a<1&&(d=a=0),w=s.search`
`+1,h=-~s.length/w,a=3,d=p=1)|p
```

### Explanation

Since the specifications are not stated clearly, this makes a couple of assumptions:

- The bottom line is the 14,000ft mark (so all positions on the grid are high enough to count as a peak).
- The grid starts at (or ascending) the first peak (since it's at least 14,000ft high already as per previous assumption).
- A separate peak counts only after descending 300ft *then ascending 300ft*.

Iterates over the character `c` of each column (specifically, it iterates down each column until it finds a character). The current altitude is stored in `a`. It is clamped to a minimum of `0` and a maximum of `3`. The direction needed to move to count the next peak is stored in `d` (`false` = up, `true` = down). If `a` reaches `3` and `d` is `false`, the number of peaks `p` is incremented and `d` is set to `true` (down). Once `a` reaches `0`, `d` is set back to `false` (up).

```js
var solution =

s=>
  [...s].map((_,i)=>   // loop
    (c=s[i%h*w+i/h|0]) // c = current character (moves down columns)
    =="/"?             // if c is '/'
      ++a>2&&          // increment a, if a equals 3 and d is true:
        (p+=!d,d=a=3)  // increment p, set d to true, clamp a to 3
    :c=="\\"&&         // if c is '\':
      --a<1&&          // decrement a, if a equals 0:
        (d=a=0),       // set d to false, clamp a to 0
    
    // Initialisation (happens BEFORE the above code)
    w=s.search`\n`+1,  // w = grid width
    h=-~s.length/w,    // h = grid height
    a=3,               // a = current altitude (min = 0, max = 3)
    d=                 // d = required direction (false = up, true = down)
    p=1                // p = number of found peaks
  )|p                  // output the number of peaks

var testCases = [`
/\\
`,`
/\\          
  \\         
   \\    /\\  
    \\  /  \\ 
     \\/    \\
`,`
\\    /
 \\  / 
  \\/  
`,`
            /\\            
         /\\/  \\/\\         
      /\\/        \\/\\      
   /\\/              \\/\\   
/\\/                    \\/\\
`,`
  /\\__/\\
 /      \\
/        \\
`,`
   /\\    /\\   
  /  \\  /  \\  
 /    \\/    \\ 
/            \\
`,`
   /\\      /\\   
  /  \\/\\  /  \\  
 /      \\/    \\ 
/              \\
`,`
         /\\___/\\_             
        /        \\    /\\      
       /          \\  /  \\     
   _/\\/            \\/    \\    
  /                       \\   
 /                         \\  
/                           \\_
`,`
                  /\\    /\\
         /\\      /  \\  /  
  /\\    /  \\    /    \\/   
 /  \\  /    \\  /          
/    \\/      \\/           
`,`
       /\\                 
 _/\\__/  \\                
/         \\               
`,`
      /\\                  
     /  \\   /\\            
    /    \\_/  \\           
   /           \\          
  /             \\         
 /               \\        
/                 \\       
`,`
              /\\          
    /\\_/\\    /  \\_        
   /     \\  /     \\     /\\
  /       \\/       \\   /  
 /                  \\_/   
/                         
`];
result.textContent = testCases.map(c=>c+"\n"+solution(c.slice(1,-1))).join`\n\n`;
```

```html
<textarea id="input" rows="6" cols="40"></textarea><br /><button onclick="result.textContent=solution(input.value)">Go</button><pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

## C, 174 bytes

```
a[99],c,p,j,M,m;main(i){for(i=j=1;c=getchar(),~c;i++)c<11?a[i]=j++,i=0:c&4?a[i]=j:0;for(m=j;c=a[i++];c>a[i-2]?M-m>1&&c-m>1?M=c,m=j,p++:M<c?M=m=c:M:m>c?m=c:0);printf("%d",p);}
```

Requires a trailing newline in the input, otherwise +4 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 154 bytes

```
s=>s.split`\n`.map((s,i)=>s.replace(/\S/g,(c,j)=>{e[j]=i+(c!='\\');e[j+1]=i+(c>'/')}),e=[])&&e.map(n=>h-n+d?h-n-d*3?0:(c++,d=-d,h=n):h=n,h=e[0],c=d=1)|c>>1
```

Where `\n` represents the literal newline character. Ungolfed:

```
function climb(string) {
    var heights = [];
    // Split the array into lines so that we know the offset of each char
    var array = string.split("\n");
    // Calculate the height (actually depth) before and after each char
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < string.length; j++) {
            switch (array[i][j]) {
            case '\':
                heights[j] = i;
                heights[j+1] = i + 1;
                break;
            case '_':
                heights[j] = i + 1;
                heights[j+1] = i + 1;
                break;
            case '/':
                heights[j] = i + 1;
                heights[j+1] = i;
                break;
        }
    }
    var count = 1;
    // Start by looking for an upward direction
    var direction = 1;
    var height = heights[0];
    for (var k = 1; k < heights.length; k++) {
        if (heights[i] == height - direction * 3) { // peak or trough
            direction *= -1;
            count++; // we're counting changes of direction = peaks * 2
            height = heights[i];
        } else if (heights[i] == height + direction) {
            // Track the current peak or trough to the tip or base
            height = heights[i];
        }
    }
    return count >> 1;
}
```